# Repeating header image CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a repeating header image which appears in top of the page. The issue is it leaves some blank space in left and right. How can I make the image appear in full width of the page? Here is what I have done.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

      <style>
      .bgimg{
      min-height: 44px;
      background: url("img/top-bar.png") repeat top left;
      }
      </style>

      <html>
      <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      </head>

       <body>
        <header>
          <div class="bgimg">
         </div>
        </header>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Please provide an online example to demonstrate the issue in action. I cannot reproduce the problem using the current given code.

Comment: You probably need a reset css sheet. Browsers by default has padding and margin (among others) values for some elements. Anyway try body {margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: Every browser has some pre-defined styles for elements, body usually has margin, so try `body {margin: 0;}`

Comment: A screenshot would also be useful. And you should put the `style` tag inside the `head` tag -- it is not 100% necessary, but that is where it belongs.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for my page [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3jpbczpe/1/). Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you see the margin of your body tag, remove the margin of the boby tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <style>
  .bgimg{
  min-height: 70px;
  background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/128/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png") ;
  }
  </style>

  <html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>

   <body style="margin:0px">
    <header>
      <div class="bgimg">
     </div>
    </header>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Great! It works. Like skobaljic said overriding body margin did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser by default has its own css rules over all elements to make non styled websites more legible, that is why you are seeing a margin even though you haven't set that rule.

It is usual to use a reset css so you don't have to lead with this problems.

Here's an article that
[explains the use of a reset css](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Here's a [common reset css from html5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) that I use.